# How can I avoid broken languages when unzipping unicode files?

Tags: unicode, unzip

It happens often that I see unknown file names when uncompressing zip files.

For example,

```
 ╕╢╣¤└╟╝║-Bb└╠┴╢╛╟▒т┐ы-┼м╢є╕о│▌,┼╫│╩╗Ў╝╥╞∙ ╝╥╟┴╢є│ы╗Ў╝╥╞∙ ,╞о╖│╞ъ
```

What could be the solution for the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, the anwser is related with html2txt, which is different from uncompressing tool.

Answer (score 7):

[Korean MS Windows encoding cp-949](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_949) may be used to zip the original files. Try `unzip` with Windows Encoding option.

```
unzip -O cp-949 <file.zip>
```

**Note:** I checked the profile of original poster to know from where he/she is (Seoul, South Korea). For other users, you have to check the origin of zip and change the encoding respectively.

Comment: This seems the better answer.  @user.dz both notes the problem - character encoding - and the (unfortunately) brute force method to solve the problem.  It seems ZIP should capture metadata like encoding being used.

Answer (score 7):

Try using p7zip. (@Pilot6 mentioned that p7zip doesn't work well for non UTF-8 encodings, but if you only need for UTF-8, then that's an easy solution.)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install p7zip-full
7z x thefile.zip -o"outputDir"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use standard Ubuntu Archive Manager and Ubuntu version 14.04+, then this can be solved by installing patched Archive Manager (file-roller). The problem is that file-roller uses p7zip for unzipping zip archives, if p7zip-full is installed. But p7zip does not handle non-UTF-8 encodings well. I patched file-roller to always use unzip for that purpose. Unzip itself has been fixed. 
The patched file-roller can be installed from my ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/file-roller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install file-roller
```

Comment: Installed Ubuntu version 15.04 and your answer has just been tried. Still, the problem is to be solved.

Comment: Maybe a little more time is needed to be reflected officially.

Comment: That must be a different problem. But is you use just unzip in CLI, does it work OK? It works well for Russian and Greek encodings, but your case must be different. I want to find out where the problem is.

Comment: I would appreciate your help. I tried unzip both in CLI and Unity. The language is Korean(Hangul). Your e-mail address is wanted to send my zip files, if you don't mind.

Comment: So unzip does not handle this right? In this case my solution won't help. I suggest reporting a bug in launchpad. Unzip tries to convert filenames coorectly based on your system language. Is it set to Korean?

Comment: And also you can try to install p7zip-full.

Comment: I attach urls for the files. Be my guest.

Comment: http://www.umtf.or.kr/common/include/file_down.php?fileidx=969

Comment: http://www.umtf.or.kr/common/include/file_down.php?fileidx=968

Answer (score 0):

miniunzip in package minizip also seems to work fine with non-ascii filenames

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in two ways:

```
unzip -O cp936 file.zip
unzip -O GBK file.zip
```